# kubernetes, port omitted when ingress-nginx redirects

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I have a small cluster, and there are three external services. I use clusterIP as internal pod communication. Then I use ingress(nginx) as inverse proxy. The ingress connects internet to cluster.

When nginx redirects traffic, but did not sent port with domain. For example, ykt:31080/workflow redirects to ykt/workflow/login, it omits the port 31080. Then server could not find the page.

My ingress resource is configured as follows:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  rules:
   - host: ykt
     http:
       paths:
       - path: /business
         backend:
           serviceName: core-ykt
           servicePort: 80
   - host: ykt
     http:
       paths:
       - path: /pre
         backend:
           serviceName: pre-core-ykt
           servicePort: 80
   - host: ykt
     http:
       paths:
       - path: /workflow
         backend:
           serviceName: virtual-apply-ykt
           servicePort: 80
```

And part of my ingress controller is configured as follows:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: ingress-nginx
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    nodePort: 31080
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ingress-nginx
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      serviceAccount: lb
      containers:
      - image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.15.0
        name: ingress-nginx
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 80
            protocol: TCP
          - name: https
            containerPort: 443
            protocol: TCP
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        env:
          - name: POD_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: POD_NAMESPACE
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-default-backend
```

================================================

## Second edition

datalook_virtual_apply_pod.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: virtual-apply-ykt
  labels:
    app: virtual-apply-ykt
    purpose: ykt_production
spec:
  containers:
  - name: virtual-apply-ykt
    image: app
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    ports:
      - containerPort: 80
    volumeMounts:
      - name: volume-virtual-apply-ykt
        mountPath: /usr/application
    env:
      - name: spring.config.location
        value: application.properties
  volumes:
      - name: volume-virtual-apply-ykt
        hostPath:
          path: /opt/docker/datalook-virtual-apply
          type: Directory
```

datalook_virtual_apply_svc.yaml file is as follows, I have no deployment file for datalook_virtual_apply service.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: virtual-apply-ykt
  labels:
    name: virtual-apply-ykt
spec:
  selector:
    app: virtual-apply-ykt
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
      name: tcp
```

/////////////////////////////
second edition
///////////////////////////////

The backend generated nginx configuation is as follows: instead let application listen to 80, May I make ingress-nginx default port as 31080?

```
daemon off;

worker_processes 1;

pid /run/nginx.pid;

worker_rlimit_nofile 1047552;

worker_shutdown_timeout 10s ;

events {
    multi_accept        on;
    worker_connections  16384;
    use                 epoll;
}

http {

    lua_package_cpath "/usr/local/lib/lua/?.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.1/?.so;;";
    lua_package_path "/etc/nginx/lua/?.lua;/etc/nginx/lua/vendor/?.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/?.lua;;";

    init_by_lua_block {
        require("resty.core")
        collectgarbage("collect")

        local lua_resty_waf = require("resty.waf")
        lua_resty_waf.init()

    }

    real_ip_header      X-Forwarded-For;

    real_ip_recursive   on;

    set_real_ip_from    0.0.0.0/0;

    geoip_country       /etc/nginx/geoip/GeoIP.dat;
    geoip_city          /etc/nginx/geoip/GeoLiteCity.dat;
    geoip_org           /etc/nginx/geoip/GeoIPASNum.dat;
    geoip_proxy_recursive on;

    aio                 threads;
    aio_write           on;

    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;

    log_subrequest      on;

    reset_timedout_connection on;

    keepalive_timeout  75s;
    keepalive_requests 100;

    client_header_buffer_size       1k;
    client_header_timeout           60s;
    large_client_header_buffers     4 8k;
    client_body_buffer_size         8k;
    client_body_timeout             60s;

    http2_max_field_size            4k;
    http2_max_header_size           16k;

    types_hash_max_size             2048;
    server_names_hash_max_size      1024;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size   32;
    map_hash_bucket_size            64;

    proxy_headers_hash_max_size     512;
    proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size  64;

    variables_hash_bucket_size      128;
    variables_hash_max_size         2048;

    underscores_in_headers          off;
    ignore_invalid_headers          on;

    limit_req_status                503;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type text/html;

    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_types application/atom+xml application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/rss+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon text/css text/plain text/x-component;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_vary on;

    # Custom headers for response

    server_tokens on;

    # disable warnings
    uninitialized_variable_warn off;

    # Additional available variables:
    # $namespace
    # $ingress_name
    # $service_name
    log_format upstreaminfo '$the_real_ip - [$the_real_ip] - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" $request_length $request_time [$proxy_upstream_name] $upstream_addr $upstream_response_length $upstream_response_time $upstream_status $req_id';

    map $request_uri $loggable {

        default 1;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log upstreaminfo if=$loggable;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;

    resolver 10.96.0.10 valid=30s;

    # Retain the default nginx handling of requests without a "Connection" header
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default          upgrade;
        ''               close;
    }

    map $http_x_forwarded_for $the_real_ip {

        default          $remote_addr;

    }

    # trust http_x_forwarded_proto headers correctly indicate ssl offloading
    map $http_x_forwarded_proto $pass_access_scheme {
        default          $http_x_forwarded_proto;
        ''               $scheme;
    }

    # validate $pass_access_scheme and $scheme are http to force a redirect
    map "$scheme:$pass_access_scheme" $redirect_to_https {
        default          0;
        "http:http"      1;
        "https:http"     1;
    }

    map $http_x_forwarded_port $pass_server_port {
        default           $http_x_forwarded_port;
        ''                $server_port;
    }

    map $pass_server_port $pass_port {
        443              443;
        default          $pass_server_port;
    }

    # Obtain best http host
    map $http_host $this_host {
        default          $http_host;
        ''               $host;
    }

    map $http_x_forwarded_host $best_http_host {
        default          $http_x_forwarded_host;
        ''               $this_host;
    }

    # Reverse proxies can detect if a client provides a X-Request-ID header, and pass it on to the backend server.
    # If no such header is provided, it can provide a random value.
    map $http_x_request_id $req_id {
        default   $http_x_request_id;
        ""        $request_id;
    }

    server_name_in_redirect off;
    port_in_redirect        off;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;

    # turn on session caching to drastically improve performance

    ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;

    # allow configuring ssl session tickets
    ssl_session_tickets on;

    # slightly reduce the time-to-first-byte
    ssl_buffer_size 4k;

    # allow configuring custom ssl ciphers
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_ecdh_curve auto;

    proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;

    upstream upstream-default-backend {
        least_conn;

        keepalive 32;

        server 192.168.38.188:8080 max_fails=0 fail_timeout=0;

    }

    upstream default-gearbox-rack-api-gateway-5555 {
        least_conn;

        keepalive 32;

        server 192.168.38.22:5555 max_fails=0 fail_timeout=0;

    }

    ## start server _
    server {
        server_name _ ;

        listen 80 default_server  backlog=511;

        listen [::]:80 default_server  backlog=511;

        set $proxy_upstream_name "-";

        listen 443  default_server  backlog=511 ssl http2;

        listen [::]:443  default_server  backlog=511 ssl http2;

        # PEM sha: c1e1519ef05c8531e334ee947817a2ad495fe83a
        ssl_certificate                         /ingress-controller/ssl/default-fake-certificate.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key                     /ingress-controller/ssl/default-fake-certificate.pem;

        location / {

            log_by_lua_block {

            }

            if ($scheme = https) {
                more_set_headers                        "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains";
            }

            access_log off;

            port_in_redirect off;

            set $proxy_upstream_name "upstream-default-backend";

            set $namespace      "";
            set $ingress_name   "";
            set $service_name   "";

            client_max_body_size                    "1m";

            proxy_set_header Host                   $best_http_host;

            # Pass the extracted client certificate to the backend

            # Allow websocket connections
            proxy_set_header                        Upgrade           $http_upgrade;

            proxy_set_header                        Connection        $connection_upgrade;

            proxy_set_header X-Request-ID           $req_id;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP              $the_real_ip;

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $the_real_ip;

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host       $best_http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port       $pass_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto      $pass_access_scheme;

            proxy_set_header X-Original-URI         $request_uri;

            proxy_set_header X-Scheme               $pass_access_scheme;

            # Pass the original X-Forwarded-For
            proxy_set_header X-Original-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;

            # mitigate HTTPoxy Vulnerability
            # https://www.nginx.com/blog/mitigating-the-httpoxy-vulnerability-with-nginx/
            proxy_set_header Proxy                  "";

            # Custom headers to proxied server

            proxy_connect_timeout                   5s;
            proxy_send_timeout                      60s;
            proxy_read_timeout                      60s;

            proxy_buffering                         "off";
            proxy_buffer_size                       "4k";
            proxy_buffers                           4 "4k";
            proxy_request_buffering                 "on";

            proxy_http_version                      1.1;

            proxy_cookie_domain                     off;
            proxy_cookie_path                       off;

            # In case of errors try the next upstream server before returning an error
            proxy_next_upstream                     error timeout invalid_header http_502 http_503 http_504;
            proxy_next_upstream_tries               0;

            proxy_pass http://upstream-default-backend;

            proxy_redirect                          off;

        }

        # health checks in cloud providers require the use of port 80
        location /healthz {

            access_log off;
            return 200;
        }

        # this is required to avoid error if nginx is being monitored
        # with an external software (like sysdig)
        location /nginx_status {

            allow 127.0.0.1;

            allow ::1;

            deny all;

            access_log off;
            stub_status on;
        }

    }
    ## end server _

    ## start server master8g
    server {
        server_name master8g ;

        listen 80;

        listen [::]:80;

        set $proxy_upstream_name "-";

        location / {

            log_by_lua_block {

            }

            port_in_redirect off;

            set $proxy_upstream_name "default-gearbox-rack-api-gateway-5555";

            set $namespace      "default";
            set $ingress_name   "my-ingress";
            set $service_name   "gearbox-rack-api-gateway";

            client_max_body_size                    "1m";

            proxy_set_header Host                   $best_http_host;

            # Pass the extracted client certificate to the backend

            # Allow websocket connections
            proxy_set_header                        Upgrade           $http_upgrade;

            proxy_set_header                        Connection        $connection_upgrade;

            proxy_set_header X-Request-ID           $req_id;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP              $the_real_ip;

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $the_real_ip;

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host       $best_http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port       $pass_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto      $pass_access_scheme;

            proxy_set_header X-Original-URI         $request_uri;

            proxy_set_header X-Scheme               $pass_access_scheme;

            # Pass the original X-Forwarded-For
            proxy_set_header X-Original-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;

            # mitigate HTTPoxy Vulnerability
            # https://www.nginx.com/blog/mitigating-the-httpoxy-vulnerability-with-nginx/
            proxy_set_header Proxy                  "";

            # Custom headers to proxied server

            proxy_connect_timeout                   5s;
            proxy_send_timeout                      60s;
            proxy_read_timeout                      60s;

            proxy_buffering                         "off";
            proxy_buffer_size                       "4k";
            proxy_buffers                           4 "4k";
            proxy_request_buffering                 "on";

            proxy_http_version                      1.1;

            proxy_cookie_domain                     off;
            proxy_cookie_path                       off;

            # In case of errors try the next upstream server before returning an error
            proxy_next_upstream                     error timeout invalid_header http_502 http_503 http_504;
            proxy_next_upstream_tries               0;

            proxy_pass http://default-gearbox-rack-api-gateway-5555;

            proxy_redirect                          off;

        }

    }
    ## end server master8g

    # default server, used for NGINX healthcheck and access to nginx stats
    server {
        # Use the port 18080 (random value just to avoid known ports) as default port for nginx.
        # Changing this value requires a change in:
        # https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/controllers/nginx/pkg/cmd/controller/nginx.go
        listen 18080 default_server  backlog=511;
        listen [::]:18080 default_server  backlog=511;
        set $proxy_upstream_name "-";

        location /healthz {

            access_log off;
            return 200;
        }

        location /is-dynamic-lb-initialized {

            access_log off;

            content_by_lua_block {
                local configuration = require("configuration")
                local backend_data = configuration.get_backends_data()
                if not backend_data then
                ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                return
                end

                ngx.say("OK")
                ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_OK)
            }
        }

        location /nginx_status {
            set $proxy_upstream_name "internal";

            access_log off;
            stub_status on;

        }

        location / {

            set $proxy_upstream_name "upstream-default-backend";

            proxy_pass          http://upstream-default-backend;

        }

    }
}

stream {
    log_format log_stream [$time_local] $protocol $status $bytes_sent $bytes_received $session_time;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log log_stream;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    # TCP services

    # UDP services

}
```

Comment: Your ingress redirects the request to the workflow-service on the `servicePort` you defined. So actually the request will always end on port 80 in the deployment/pod.
Can you define the URL of the application in the deployment? In many cases there's a configuration of a base URL.

Comment: @Marius Thank you for your help. How to define the URL of the application in the deployment, what kind of extra information do you need to help me in this issue?

Comment: @user84592 could you share Services for your deployments?

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev Thank you for your help. Ingress service and deployment is listed as original question. I here listed virtual-apply-ykt's pod and service yaml file. Please see second edition in the question.

Comment: Looks like @Marius right, you need to configure your application to wait on `port 80` instead of `31080`, cause `31080` is the ingress port only.

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev how to configure my application to wait on port 80? How to define the URL of the application in the deployment?  It only happens on rewrite and redirects to login page. Rewrite/redirects in the application use relative  URL. We are using shiro framework to handle rewrite/redirect.

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev May I make nginx default port as 31080, so that  application respond 31080 back which is nginx and NodePort's port, so there would be no port problem? See my second edition in the question which is nginx configuration generated from ingress-nginx configuration.

Comment: @Marius May I make nginx default port as 31080, so that application respond 31080 back which is nginx and NodePort's port, so there would be no port problem? See my second edition in the question which is nginx configuration generated from ingress-nginx configuration.

Comment: Finally，I make port as 80. I changed service port range from 80-32767. Now it works.